# Bash array access not working as expected

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk

I am re-writing code to work with a newer system. I did not write the original code, but I'm trying to use the old code as a template. When I run the command by itself, it works fine. When I try running it as part of a script or function in the shell, it does not.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
function find_user() {
    local txt
    local user_list
    local username
    local displayName

    echo "Find User"
    echo "---------"

    echo -n "Enter search text (e.g: lib): "
    read txt

    if [ -z "$txt" ] || ! validate_fullname "$txt"; then
        echo "Search cancelled."
    else
        echo
        user_list="$(samba-tool user list | grep -i ${txt} | sort)"
        (
            echo "Username Full_Name"
            echo "-------- ---------"
            # Dev Note: Get the username, then displayName parameter, replacing
            # the spaces in displayName with an underscore. Do not need to look
            # for a dollar sign anymore, as computers are not listed as "user"
            # class objects in AD.
            for a in "${user_list[@]}"; do
                username=$a
                displayName="$(
                    samba-tool user show ${a} | grep 'displayName:' | \
                        awk -F: '{gsub(/^[ \t]+/,"""",$2); gsub(/ ./,""_"",$3); print $2}' | \
                        tr ' ' '_')"
                echo "${username} ${displayName}"
            done
        )| column -t
     fi
}
```

When I try to run it, and enter the `find_user` function, it prompts for the search text (i.e. I can type `js`) and press Enter.

My issue is with the `$displayName=` part. It seems to generate an empty string when running in the script. If I run the command manually from the terminal (filling in, for example, `jsmith` as a substitute for `${a}`), it outputs the full name correctly.

My system is running bash.

What is going on, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Edit question to show first line of script (`#!…`), and to show how you call `find_user`.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Is that acceptable? It's part of a much larger script. I am calling the script as a test by copying and pasting the function into a bash shell, and typing `find_user` to start it

Comment: That is not a good question title because you do not run the same code in an interactive shell and in a script. If you had replaced `$a` with `jsmith` in the script, then the script would have worked, too.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Suggestion on what I could say for the title?

Comment: Perhaps something like *array access does not work as expected*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `user_list` is accessed as an array

```
for a in "${user_list[@]}"
```

but set as a string:

```
user_list="$(samba-tool user list | grep -i ${txt} | sort)"
```

Instead you need

```
IFS=$'\n'     # split on newline characters
set -o noglob # disable globbing

# assign the users to the array using the split+glob operator
# (implicitly invoked in bash when you leave a command substitution
# unquoted in list context):
user_list=( $(samba-tool user list | grep -ie "${txt}" | sort) )
```

Or better (though `bash`-specific):

```
readarray -t user_list < <(samba-tool user list)
```

(note that that one would create one empty element for each empty line of the input if any, contrary to the split+glob approach which would discard empty lines).

Comment: That worked! Thank you! Is there a decent reference to explain why I need to use the extra parenthesis?

Comment: @CanadianLuke That's just how arrays are defined. See the block **Arrays** in `man bash`. `foo=(a b c)` / `foo=( $(echo a b c) )`